# Select multiple git repository in VS2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

It's been a while since VS added support for multiple git repositories.

Despite that, I'm still not able to leverage that support.

When I open a solution in VS, some repositories are activated automatically (11, while [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-multi-repository-support?view=vs-2022) says the maximum is 10).

[image: 11 repos]

These are randomly selected (or at least, I didn't understand the logic behind, but for sure they sometimes change!).

Then, if you want to select another one, it seems there's no way to keep a multiple selection.

My solution currently have 100+ projects and, having recently switched from SVN, we haven't created nuGet packages yet (that will ultimately simplify the whole workflow).

I understand it'd be heavy to load all repos, but it'd be nice to be able to select which 10 repos to track (and maybe remember them at the next solution opening).

Any idea?

The current feature implementation seems totally useless to me.

Coming from SVN, VS + AnkhSVN was a breeze to use.